# How to inject a rootStore outside of my main component?

Tags: reactjs, mobx

I am very new to React so forgive my lack of knowledge. I am using mobx and REACT. I have created a Class, I am injecting my rootStore and then exporting.

After my export, I am calling a componenet and passing props through. For one of the components in my return, I need to have access to the rootStore. Is there a way to 'inject' that outside of my export?

I realize I'm doing a pretty poor job of explaining this. I'm hoping someone with more knowledge than I have can help.

I have tried passing the rootStore path as a prop.

```
@inject("rootStore")
@observer
class AVAdditionalOptionsPanel extends Component {

render() {
const additionalOptionsStore = this.props.rootStore.additionalOptionsStore;

return ( 
<AdditionalOptionsGroup
   additionalOptionsData={additionalFilterData.labMatrix}
   onCheck={() => additionalOptionsStore.onCheckOption('labMatrix', 'Lab 
           Matrix')}
   labelText={"Lab matrix"}
   alertEntityName={"Lab matrix"}
   dsHeadingLabel={"Lab matrix"}
   store={additionalOptionsStore.additionalDSStore}
/>
}

export default AVAdditionalOptionsPanel;

const AdditionalOptionsGroup = observer(({additionalOptionsData, onCheck, labelText, alertEntityName, dsHeadingLabel, store}) => {

return (
<FormGroup
   elementType={elementTypes.checkbox}
   value={additionalOptionsData.value}
   checked={additionalOptionsData.checked}
   elementWidth={""}
   onChange={onCheck}
   text={labelText}
   hasLabel={false}
   additionalFormGroupClasses={"noborder"}
/>
<DuelingSelect
    store={store}
    availableHeading={`Available ${dsHeadingLabel} 
                     (${additionalOptionsData.availableOptions.length})`}
    selectedHeading={`Selected ${dsHeadingLabel} 
                    (${additionalOptionsData.selectedOptions.length})`}
/>
```

In the DuelingSelect component at the bottom. I need store={this.props.rootStore.additionalOptionsStore.additionalDSstore} but I have no way of accessing the rootStore there because it is being injected above.

Is there a way to do that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to inject like this: inject('rootStore')(observer(Your Component))

```
    const AdditionalOptionsGroup = inject('rootStore')(observer(({additionalOptionsData, onCheck, labelText, alertEntityName, dsHeadingLabel, store}) => {

    return (
    <FormGroup
       elementType={elementTypes.checkbox}
       value={additionalOptionsData.value}
       checked={additionalOptionsData.checked}
       elementWidth={""}
       onChange={onCheck}
       text={labelText}
       hasLabel={false}
       additionalFormGroupClasses={"noborder"}
    />
    <DuelingSelect
        store={store}
        availableHeading={`Available ${dsHeadingLabel} 
                         (${additionalOptionsData.availableOptions.length})`}
        selectedHeading={`Selected ${dsHeadingLabel} 
                        (${additionalOptionsData.selectedOptions.length})`}
    />
     );
}))
```

Comment: Thank you for being able to decipher my question! 

Ok, I have added that and updated 

store = {this.props.rootStore.additionalOptionsStore.additionalDSStore}


I am receiving the same error - TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined. 

I also tried calling it without props. 

I'm starting to think I may need to make this a new class component rather than a const. 

Any additional thoughts?

Comment: I decided to just create a new class component. 

Thank you for your input!